# xforms: how to prevent xxforms:default value from over-writing user input

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have a dropdown to display status, which can be Enabled(true) or Disabled(false). Here is my xml instance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <page>
        <file-name></file-name>
        <status></status>
    </page>
```

By default, status should be true. So I have set it in binding as follows.

```
<xforms:bind nodeset="./status" xxforms:default="true()" />
```

When user chooses Disabled in the dropdown, the status should get saved as false. Here is the xml that gets saved when I save the form.

```
<page>
    <file-name>StatusDisabled.xml</file-name>
    <status>false</false>
</page>
```

When I open the form in edit mode, this is the xml I get in the XML inspector widget.

```
<page>
    <file-name>StatusDisabled.xml</file-name>
    <status>true></status>
</page>
```

Status gets set to true because of xxforms:default, even though the xml is saved with a false value for status.

How can I fix this?

Here is the xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">

    <head>
        <title>XForms Default</title>

        <xforms:model>
            <xforms:instance id="instance">
                <page>
                    <name xmlns=""/>    
                    <status xmlns=""/>
                </page>
            </xforms:instance>

            <xforms:instance id="status-instance">
                <items>
                    <item label="Enabled" value="true" xmlns=""/>
                    <item label="Disabled" value="false" xmlns=""/>
                </items>
            </xforms:instance>

            <xforms:bind nodeset="instance('instance')">
                <xforms:bind nodeset="./status" xxforms:default="true()" />
            </xforms:bind>

        </xforms:model>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <xforms:input ref="instance('instance')/name" incremental="true">
                <xforms:label>Please enter your name:</xforms:label>
            </xforms:input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <xforms:select1 ref="instance('instance')/status" appearance="minimal" incremental="true">
                <xforms:label>Please select status:</xforms:label>
                <xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('status-instance')/item">
                    <xforms:label ref="./@label"/>
                    <xforms:value ref="./@value"/>
                </xforms:itemset>
            </xforms:select1> 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Purni,

This sounds like a bug to me: with the `xxforms:default="true()"` the value should be initialized to `true` if it is empty when the form is first loaded. But then if the user selects a value, and `false` is stored in the instance, that `false` should stay there. Would you be able to create a minimal example that runs in the XForms sandbox and shows this? If possible, you can edit your question to paste in such an example, so we can better understand what is going on here. -Alex

Comment: @Alessandro - I have edited my question and given you step by step examples.

Comment: thank you, but I would need a single XHTML+XForms file that I can run in the XForms sandbox to reproduce the problem. Otherwise I'll have to write code guessing what you have, and trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Alessandro - I have edited the initial question to now include the XHTML. Hope this helps.

Comment: Purni, what do you mean exactly by "When I open the form in edit mode"? How do you do that? Your example doesn't show this. Do you mean you are using Form Runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens, it's a bug. `xxforms:default` should only be evaluated once.

Comment: I have edited my question with step-by-step examples. It looks like a bug to me. Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: I 've also have this problem with Orbeon 4.5! Is a know bug? What can we do in this situation?

Comment: The original question was from 2010. We don't have a known bug with this right now as far as we know.

Comment: Ok, you are right, i had a mistake in my code! Sorry!